# No Module named "Fastai" when trying to deploy fastai model on sagemaker

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, fast-ai

I have trained and built a Fastai(v1) model and exported it as a .pkl file.
Now i want to deploy this model for inference in Amazon Sagemaker

Following the Sagemaker documentation for Pytorch model [https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#write-an-inference-script][1]

Steps taken
Folder structure

```
Sagemaker/
       export.pkl
       code/
           inference.py
           requirement.txt
```

```
 
requirement.txt

    spacy==2.3.4
    torch==1.4.0
    torchvision==0.5.0
    fastai==1.0.60
    numpy
```

Command i used to create the zip file

```
    cd Sagemaker/
    tar -czvf /tmp/model.tar.gz ./export.pkl ./code
```

This would generate a model.tar.gz file and i upload it to S3 bucket

To deploy this i used the python sagemaker SDK

```
    from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorchModel
        role = "sagemaker-role-arn"
        model_path = "s3 key for the model.tar.gz file that i created above"
        pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data=model_path,role=role,`entry_point='inference.py',framework_version="1.4.0", py_version="py3")
    
        predictor = pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.c5.large', initial_instance_count=1)
```

After executing the above code i see that the model is created in sagemaker and deployed but i end up getting an error running the inference

```
    botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "No module named 'fastai'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 110, in transform
        self.validate_and_initialize(model_dir=model_dir)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 157, in validate_and_initialize
        self._validate_user_module_and_set_functions()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 170, in _validate_user_module_and_set_functions
        user_module = importlib.import_module(user_module_name)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 2, in <module>
        from fastai.basic_train import load_learner, DatasetType, Path
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai'
```

Clearly the fastai module doesn't get downloaded what is the cause for this and what am i doing wrong in this case

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot such issues, you should check the [CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-cloudwatch.html) for the endpoint.

You should check the logs first to see if the `requirements.txt` was found and installed or if there were any dependency errors.

For packaging the model and your inference scripts, it's recommended to have two files:

1. `model.tar.gz` which has the model and the model files.
2. `sourcedir.tar.gz` and use SageMaker environment variable `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY` to point to the file location on S3 `s3://bucket/prefix/sourcedir.tar.gz`. You can point to the file name using `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM` to be `inference.py`.

Note: when you use `source_dir` in [PyTorchModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html#pytorch-model), the SDK will package the `source_dir`, upload it to s3 and define `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY`.